# Unable to execute C binary on costum Buildroot

Tags: c, buildroot

I'm unable to execute a C program on my ARM Cortex A7 running buildroot.
After executing I get this error:

./mcp23017

Could not open file (1): No such file or directory

After searching I found out that I'm missing the correct interpreter on my buildroot.

`#cd /lib`

```
ls
dhcpcd               
libform.so           libncurses.so.6.0
ld-uClibc-1.0.28.so  libform.so.6         libpanel.so
ld-uClibc.so.0       libform.so.6.0       libpanel.so.6 
ld-uClibc.so.1       libgcc_s.so          libpanel.so.6.0
libatomic.so         libgcc_s.so.1        libuClibc-1.0.28.so
libatomic.so.1       libmagic.so          libz.so
libatomic.so.1.2.0   libmagic.so.1        libz.so.1
libc.so.0            libmagic.so.1.0.0    libz.so.1.2.11
libc.so.1            libmenu.so           modules
libcurl.so           libmenu.so.6         os-release
libcurl.so.4         libmenu.so.6.0       terminfo
libcurl.so.4.5.0     libncurses.so
libcurses.so         libncurses.so.6
```

I'm really stuck, could you tell me how I can cross compile with uclibc on my i386 laptop?
Or do I have other options?

Answer (score 4):

You must build your program with the cross-compiler provided by Buildroot, so that it uses the libraries matching the ones available on your ARM target. The compiler is `host/bin/arm-linux-gcc`.